# Changing logo in admin theme

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, logo

I am trying to simple change the logo shown on the admin login page. After creating the following files i have run

```
magento setup:upgrade
magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
magento setup:di:compile
magento cache:clean
```

app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>My custom admin theme</title>
<parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/registration.php

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme',
__DIR__
);
```

app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mycustom_logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">283</argument>
                <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">85</argument>\
                <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">custom_logo</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_logo.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/mycustom_logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">283</argument> <!-- Add custom logo width -->
                <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">85</argument> <!-- Add custom logo height -->
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

the di.xml file in etc folder of my working module is as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
             <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme</item>
             </argument>
         </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

despite all this the logo stays the same. however when i open the logo image in new tab, i can see that the default magento logo is pulled from static/version1704465742/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/en_US/images/magento-logo.svg

So, the theme is working but the default.xml or admin_logo.xml is not. Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong, the magento version is 2.4

Comment: Hi, Could you please check the recent posted answer to your question. This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All Seems correct exclude:

No need of

> app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml

Change file name from:

`app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_logo.xml` to `app/design/adminhtml/Myvendor/mycustomadmintheme/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_login.xml`

Make Sure Your module, where you defined di.xml loading after Magento_Theme module [prerequisites](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/apply-admin/#prerequisites)

A detail explanation about Admin Theme and update logo can be found on official ADOBE doc [Link](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/create-admin/#admin-theme-logo-optional)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues, and after the modifications, the logo will load properly.

**First Issue:**

I have utilized the same/your code and discovered that there is an code issue in your default.xml

**Solution:**

I have applied the following code in default.xml and the logo appears to load properly after admin login. Here is the default.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Header" name="logo" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/admin-logo.png</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Second Issue:**

The admin login file name is incorrect.

**Solution:**

Please rename admin_logo.xml to admin_login.xml as this file loads the logo on the Magento login screen. Other than that, the xml code is fine.

**Note:** I have tested the code changes on my end and everything seems to be working correctly.

**Here are the screenshots:**
[image]

[image]